# Precision degree numerical integration

Tags: numerical-methods

How should I understand precision degree?
I know that if the number of nodes $n$ is even the precision degree is $n+1$ and if it's odd its $n$.

Does this mean that if for a example we are calculating for a polynomial of the $8$th degree, the error is $0$ if the precision degree is $8$ or more?

Comment: Yes, the degree of a formula is the highest degree a polynomial can have such that the formula gives the exact value.

Comment: I understand, thank you! We know that the precision degree of the trapezium rule is 1 and for the 1/3-simpson rule it is 3. What about the newton cotes formulas?